# how to pass the click event under the TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

Tags: android, overlay

I following the code from https://github.com/noln/system-alert-window-example.

and using the below code

private void addOverlayView() {

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params =
        new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat);

params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.START;
params.x = 0;
params.y = 0;

FrameLayout interceptorLayout = new FrameLayout(this) {

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    // Only fire on the ACTION_DOWN event, or you'll get two events (one for _DOWN, one for _UP)
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

      // Check if the HOME button is pressed
      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        Log.v(TAG, "BACK Button Pressed");

        // As we've taken action, we'll return true to prevent other apps from consuming the event as well
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Otherwise don't intercept the event
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }
};

floatyView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.floating_view, interceptorLayout);

floatyView.setOnTouchListener(this);

windowManager.addView(floatyView, params);
```

It is working without problem. But this Layout is block the click event on original app.

Could anyone help me to find a way that a user can click under this app frame layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE 
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
```

More Information [click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams)

Comment: Thanks, removed this line added FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE